# recursive search on tgz file

Tags: search, tar

I have several tgz files with several folders inside each file. I would like to find a file (which is inside one of those folders) with a specific name within all the tgz withouth extracting them.

I tried something like:

```
find -r . -name Cal-CableCorrections.nc | tar -tf *.tgz
```

But I doesn't find the file and ends with some error.

Any ideas?